# update array subfield mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema  and I manage to perform a FindOneAndUpate query without problems. But to do so, I have to provide all the fields in order to update just 1 object in 1 of the several arrays which is very inconvenient.

I tried to use $set but seems ineffective. I am posting the code and hoping to get some help. Thanks in advance.

```
var comandaSchema =  mongoose.Schema({

mesa: {type: Object},

fechaorden: {type: Date, default: Date.now},

orden: [{


    postres:  [{

        idapoyo:idapoyoSchema,

        postre:String,

        estadoitem: String,

        contorno:[]

    }],

    bebidas:  [{

        idapoyo:idapoyoSchema,

        bebida:String,

        estadoitem: String,

        contorno:[]

    }], 

    fondos:   [{

        idapoyo:idapoyoSchema,

        fondo:String,

        estadoitem: String,

        contorno:[]

    }],

    entradas: [{

        idapoyo:idapoyoSchema,

        entrada:String,

        estadoitem: String,

        contorno:[]

    }]


}],

estado_orden: {type: String},

estado_bebida: {type: String},

estado_pcuenta: {type: String},

estado_pago: {type: String}

});

  var Comanda = module.exports = mongoose.model('Comanda', comandaSchema);
```

and my update function:

```
app.put('/api/estadofondo/:_id', function(req, res){
var id = req.params._id;
var comanda = req.body;
Comanda.findOneAndUpdate(id, {"$set":  ["orden.fondos"] }, {}, function(err, comanda){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(comanda);
});
});
```

I'm sending this json to update  "estadoitem": "ready"

```
{
"fondos": [
      {
        "contorno": [
          "Extra Tocineta",
          "Champiñon"
        ],
        "estadoitem": "ready",
        "fondo": "Pizza Americana"
      }]
}
```

which is originally "estadoitem": "not ready", but like i said nothing happens, so I would appreciate if I could get some help. Again, thanks.

EDIT: I was also wondering if I could update just the field "estadoitem" with something like $set : [orden.fondos.estadoitem]. I have an ID for every single item in the schema so I could somehow access that to get to the exact item

FINAL UPDATE--------

the acceted answer works all I needed was a way to dinamically set the $set

follow this [Passing parameters to the array updater method {$set: {"parameters": data}}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42381065/passing-parameters-to-the-array-updater-method-set-parameters-data/42381350#42381350) to achieve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.put('/api/estadofondo/:_id', function(req, res){
var id = req.params._id;
var comanda = req.body;
Comanda.findOneAndUpdate(id, {"$set":  {orden.0.fondos: 'object with values'} },{safe: true, upsert: true}, function(err, comanda){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(comanda);
});
});
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation

Comment: hello thanks for the reply, with the {"$set":  {orden.0.fondos: 'object with values'} }, changed to {"$set":orden.0.fondos: ' "estadoitem": "ready" '} im getting sintax error and i kind of don't understand what the 0 is for in orden.0.fondos, mind elaborate a little bit more? thanks again, edit: in the options bracket is it "safe" or "save"

Comment: ok got an update with `{"$set": {"orden.0.fondos": [comanda]}}` im doing what i need but i have 3 sets of data saved in "fondos" and it is deleting the other 2, im sending this json :  ` "contorno": [
              "Extra Tocineta",
              "Champiñon"
            ],
            "estadoitem": "listo",
            "fondo": "Pizza Americana" ` and i would like to only send the "estadoitem to a specific element

Comment: got an update with `{"$set": {"orden.0.fondos.1.estadoitem": estadoitem}}` im able to change the very specific field but is making my field an object and I need to remain a simple String.. what im doing wrong? im sending this json {
  "estadoitem": "listo"
}

Comment: 0 1 are just the index of an array

Comment: `estadoitem: String,` is string in your schema, please check

Comment: yes, `     fondos:  { type: Array,

         properties: {     

      postre:String,

      estadoitem: String,

      contorno:[]

     }, index:true},` it is a string and im trying to build an automatic slector for te array index and it does not work  `var dirtotal = diparcial += selector += dirfinal;` edit: i mean i log the var console.log(dirtotal); it shows orden.0.fondos.0.estadoitem but if i pass dirtotal to {"$set": {dirtotal:estadoitem}} wont do anything

Comment: make dirtotal `orden.0.fondos.$.estadoitem` 
 
and please visit 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation

Comment: yes bro, I get the dot-notation, I went from changing the whole fondos array to the specific field I want inside the specific index, im sorry to bother you but im not very experienced with java script and if i change `{"$set": {"orden.0.fondos.0.estadoitem": estado}}` to `{"$set": {"orden.0.fondos.$.estadoitem": estado}}` I understand the $ is to send the index selector but im not familiar with doing such, how would I, and again sorry to bother

Comment: there may be many fields not just 1, so dot-notation comes handy
`{"$set": {"orden.$.fondos.$.estadoitem": estado}}`  will be effective then
`{"$set": {"orden.0.fondos.0.estadoitem": estado}}`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, seems like it is hard for me to comunicate what I need to do, so far this is an update on what i have done with the VERY appreciated help from @p0k8, with this new function I can change at will the field "estadoitem" from the array [fondos] in my model BUT  i need to be able to select the index automatically

```
app.put('/api/estadofondo/:_id', function(req, res){
var id = req.params._id;
var estadoitem = req.body;

//var directo = orden.0.fondos.$.estadoitem;
//var directo = "orden.0.fondos.0.estadoitem";

Comanda.findOneAndUpdate(id,{$set: {"orden.0.fondos.1.estadoitem": estadoitem}}, {upsert: true}, function(err, comanda){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(estadoitem);
});
});
```

I understand that somehow i have to pass index value to :

```
 {$set: {"orden.0.fondos.1.estadoitem": estadoitem}}
```

the "0" its OK there since orders will ALWAYS be 0 but the "1" could be N at any time so i need to pass that parameter to my function... this is where im stuck, as always thanks in advance.

UPDATE:***************************************

the new function is:

```
app.put('/api/estadofondo/:_id', function(req, res){
var id = req.params._id;
var estadoitem = req.body;

var $ = estadoitem.index;

var estado = estadoitem.estadoitem;

console.log($, estado);

Comanda.findOneAndUpdate(id,{$set: {"orden.0.fondos.0.estadoitem": estado}}, {upsert: true}, function(err, comanda){
//Comanda.findOneAndUpdate(id,{"$set": {estadoitem: estado}}, {safe: true, upsert: true}, function(err, comanda){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(estadoitem);
});
});
```

it works perfectly with my json

```
{



        "estadoitem": "listo",
        "index": 1



}
```

IF only I'd know WHERE to place the "$" to use it as my index selector... =/

if I do {$set: {"orden.0.fondos.$.estadoitem": estado} replacing the second "0" in {$set: {"orden.0.fondos.0.estadoitem": estado} it just crashes

NEW UPDATE*********************************************************

the new function is

```
app.put('/api/estadofondo/:_id', function(req, res){
var id = req.params._id;
var estadoitem = req.body;

var index = estadoitem.index;

var estado = estadoitem.estadoitem;

Comanda.findOneAndUpdate({_id:id, "orden.0.fondos.estadoitem": "pendiente"}, {$set: {"orden.0.fondos.$.estadoitem": estado}}, {upsert: true}, function(err, comanda){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(estadoitem);
});
});
```

it does work everytime i send the JSON, it will update the arrays in secuence BUT I still CANT update the one im telling