# Passing parameters to the array updater method {$set: {"parameters": data}}

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
Comanda.findOneAndUpdate(id,{$set: {"orden.0.fondos.2.estadoitem": estado}}, {}, function(err, comanda)
```

I need to indirectly change that "2" in

```
$set: {"orden.0.fondos.2.estadoitem"
```

no matter what I do, i cant.. this will save my live =/..

i have tried everything, calling a var pos = 2; and then  $set: {"orden.0.fondos.pos.estadoitem" also as a string pos= "2"; and nothing seems to work

thanks in advace

Comment: It seems like you can just do string concatenation as in `"orden.0.fondos." + pos + ".estadoitem"`

Comment: i have tried and it gives me this  Comanda.findOneAndUpdate(id,{$set: {"orden.0.fondos." + pos + ".estadoitem": estado}}, {}, function(err, comanda){
                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token +    seems like it does not wants operators there and if i put a variable there it just WONT take the value.. this is driving me crazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `$set` field dynamically :

```
var set = { "$set": {} };
set.$set["orden.0.fondos." + pos + ".estadoitem"] = estado;

Comanda.findOneAndUpdate(id, set, {}, function(err, comanda) {

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems orden is an array and so is fondos.

You could try

```
var doc = findOne({_id: id});
doc.orden[0].fondos[2] = 'anything you want';
doc.save((err,result)=>{})
```

Comment: yes they are arrays, fondos is one of the many arrays inside orden, ill try that